# EF 6 and Oracle using Guid as primary key

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In our application (ASP.NET MVC 5) we are using EF 6 code-first with SQL Server. Now we need to get it running using an Oracle DB (our customers don’t trust SQL Server).

We've managed to get a small test project working, but we have some problems migrating our real application.

One problem which we aren’t able to solve yet, is using `Guid` as primary key (all our classes have a `Guid` as primary key).

Something like:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid TestModelId { get; set; }
}
```

If we run `Update-Database` using the code above we get the following exception:

> Identity-Spalte muss einen numerischen Typ aufweisen = Identity-Column must be a numeric type
>
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x000077D3): ORA-30675: Identity-Spalte muss einen numerischen Typ aufweisen
>   ORA-30675: Identity-Spalte muss einen numerischen Typ aufweisen

We tried to fix this by telling Oracle/EF to make the field of type `RAW(16)`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestModel>()
                .ToTable("TESTMODEL", "MySchema");

    modelBuilder.Entity<TestModel>()
                .Property( x => x.TestModelId )
                .HasColumnType( "RAW(16)" );
}
```

After running Update-Database we are getting the following exception (Not very helpful... for us at least):

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element

The only which works seems to be removing the `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` and the type mapping:

```
public class TestModel
{
     [Key]
     //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public Guid TestModelId { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestModel>()
                .ToTable("TESTMODEL", " MySchema");

    /*modelBuilder.Entity<TestModel>()
                .Property( x => x.TestModelId )
                .HasColumnType( "RAW(16)" );*/
}
```

This generates a table which looks like this:

```
+----------------------------------+
| Name        | DataType | NotNull |
+----------------------------------+
| TestModelId | RAW(16)  | True    |
+----------------------------------+
```

But without the `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` we have to give our models manually a primary key... which we don't want to do.

How can we use `Guid` as primary key with `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` using an Oracle database?

We are using:

- EF 6.1.1
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 4.121.1.0 (ODAC 12c Release 3)
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 6.121.1.0 (ODAC 12c Release 3)

Our configuration (`web.config`):

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework"
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=ORCL;PASSWORD=PASSWORD;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=USER"
         providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
                type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />

      <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET"
           invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
           type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I think with EF you can't have a GUID as database generated ID (AFAIK!), in code first just add a Guid.NewGuid() in your class constructor.

Comment: With SQL Server GUID as database generated ID works perfectly.. is this a Oracle limitation?

Comment: Yes - Oracle (and many other databases) **don't have** a `Guid` datatype; one more really good reason ***not*** to use `Guid` (`Uniqueidentifier`) as PK in SQL Server!

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar issue and tried to use  Adriano Repetti's suggestion, which is to add "Guid.NewGuid()" in the constructor. It worked perfectly!

Comment: This should be a comment